# Range Doppler Graph

Tags: radar, doppler

The graph includes a peak at zero frequency and some other frequencies. However, my professor says that there should not be a peak at zero. I contend that he is wrong. But my graph is also not right, it should show the second-largest peak at $50 \, \textrm{m/s}$.

[image: Velocity Graph]

This is my entire code:

```
%initialize all variables
close all; clear; clc;
c = 3e8;
Range = 2000;
Range_U = 5000;
theta_az = 3.1875;
theta_el = 6.375;
freq = 10e9;
RCS = 0.1;
PD = 0.5;
PFA = 1e-6;
update_rate = 0.05;
Range_res = 5;
DC = 0.1;
Band = [8e9 12e9];
lambda = c/freq;
Spacing  = [0.5*lambda 0.5*lambda];

%% Link Budget Analysis
%constants
    K       = 1.38e-23;
    t_amb   = 20;
    v_den   = 7.5;
    rain_rate = 10;
    snow_rate = 0.75;
    training_cells = 20;
    den = 0.5;
    Pulse_canceller = 2;
    Ltf = 1;
    NF_db = 3;
    T0 = 290;
    Ta = 290;
    c = 3e8;
    pressure = 101e3;
    Trf = 225;
 %%
 %Loss Calculations
    Lgas_db = gaspl(Range, freq, t_amb, pressure, v_den);
    Lsnow_db = snowpl(Range, freq, snow_rate, 'Type', 'Wet', 'SnowModel', 'GunnEast');
    Lrain_db = rainpl(Range, freq, rain_rate);
    Lfog_db  = fogpl(Range, freq, t_amb, den);
    L_env = Lgas_db + Lsnow_db + Lrain_db + Lfog_db;
    Lcfar_db = cfarloss(PFA, training_cells, 'Method', 'CA');
    
    %%
    %Calculations
    PRF = c/(2*Range_U);
    Num_pulses = update_rate * PRF;
    Lmti_db = mtiloss(PD, PFA, Num_pulses, Pulse_canceller, 'Swerling4');
    Lsp = Lmti_db + Lcfar_db + 2;
    L_db = L_env + Lsp + Ltf;
    NF = db2pow(NF_db);
    Trcv = T0*(NF-1);
    Ts = Ta + Trf + Trcv;
    SNR_db = shnidman(PD, PFA, 1, 4);
    
    CI_gain_db = 10*log10(Num_pulses);
    SNR_db_CI = SNR_db - CI_gain_db;
    %%
    %Radar Parameters Calculations
    B = c / (2*Range_res);
    
    G = 41253/(theta_az*theta_el);
    
    lambda = c / 10e9;
    
    SNR = db2pow(SNR_db);
    
    L = db2pow(L_db);
    %%
    %Radar Range Equation
    Pt_required = (SNR * (4*pi)^3 * Range^4 * K * Ts * B * L)/(G^2 * lambda^2 * RCS);
    
    Pt_required_db = 10*log10(Pt_required);
    Pt_required_CI_db = Pt_required_db - CI_gain_db;
    %%
    %Signal Parameters
    PRI = 1/PRF;
    PW = DC * PRI;
    Pulse_comp_G = B * PW;
    Pulse_comp_G_db = 10*log10(Pulse_comp_G);
    G_db = 10*log10(G);
    %%
    %Antenna Properties
    antenna_rows = 102/theta_az;
    antenna_cols = 102/theta_el;
    antenna_aperture = gain2aperture(G_db, lambda);


%% LFM Baseband


PW = 3.33e-6;
PRF = 30e3;
BW = 30e6;
up_freq = 395e6;
fs_BB = 3*up_freq;

waveform = phased.LinearFMWaveform('SampleRate',fs_BB,'PulseWidth',PW,'PRF',PRF,'SweepBandwidth', BW,'SweepDirection','Up',...
    'Envelope','Rectangular','OutputFormat','Pulses','NumPulses',1);

Baseband = waveform();
N_BB = size(Baseband,1);

%% Sine Wave Generation

fs = 3*up_freq; % Sample rate

sinewave  = dsp.SineWave('Frequency',up_freq,'SampleRate',fs,'SamplesPerFrame',N_BB);
coswave = dsp.SineWave('Frequency',up_freq,'SampleRate',fs, 'PhaseOffset', pi/2 , 'SamplesPerFrame',N_BB);

xCos = coswave();
xSin = sinewave();

x_up = xCos .* real(Baseband) + xSin .* imag(Baseband);

%% Interpolation
up_freq_2 = 9.62e9;
fs_2 = 33.18e9;

x_up_sampled = interp(x_up, 28);
N_up_2 = size(x_up_sampled,1);

coswave = dsp.SineWave('Frequency',up_freq_2,'SampleRate',fs_2, 'PhaseOffset', pi/2 ,'SamplesPerFrame',N_up_2);

xCos = coswave();
xUp2 = xCos .* x_up_sampled;

%% Band-Pass Filtering

[sig,d] = bandpass(xUp2, [9.985 10.015]*1e9, fs_2, 'StopbandAttenuation', 120);

%% Antenna Design & Plotting
Cols = 32;
Rows = 16;

% Replicated Array of 2*Rows * Cols/2 
antenna = antenna_design2('X', Cols, Rows, 0.5 * lambda); 

%% Objects Modelling

Tx_Gain = 22;                                   % Transmission Gain
Tx_Loss = 2;                                    % Transmission Loss
Rx_Gain = 18;                                   % Receiver Gain
Rx_Loss = 2;                                    % Receiver Loss
Noise_Figure = 3;                               % Noise Figure
FS = 33.18e9;                                   % Sampling Frequency
Antenna_Position=[0;0;4];                       % Antenna Position [x y z]
Antenna_Velocity=[0;0;0];                       % Antenna Velocity [x y z]

Target_Velocity = [75;0;0];                    % Target Velocity [x y z]
%Ts = 805;                                      % System Temperature

th_az = 0;
x_c = cosd(th_az);
y_c = sind(th_az);

R = 1200;

Target_Position = [ R*x_c; R*y_c; 4];                    % Target Position [x y z]f

target = phased.RadarTarget('Model','Nonfluctuating','MeanRCS',RCS,'PropagationSpeed',physconst('LightSpeed'),'OperatingFrequency',freq);

antennaplatform = phased.Platform('InitialPosition',Antenna_Position,'Velocity',Antenna_Velocity);

targetplatform = phased.Platform('InitialPosition',Target_Position, 'Velocity',Target_Velocity);

[tgtrng,tgtang] = rangeangle(targetplatform.InitialPosition,antennaplatform.InitialPosition);

transmitter = phased.Transmitter('PeakPower',Pt_required,'Gain',Tx_Gain,'LossFactor',Tx_Loss,'InUseOutputPort',true,'CoherentOnTransmit',true);

radiator = phased.Radiator('Sensor',antenna, 'PropagationSpeed',physconst('LightSpeed'),'OperatingFrequency',freq);

collector = phased.Collector('Sensor',antenna,'PropagationSpeed',physconst('LightSpeed'),'Wavefront','Plane', 'OperatingFrequency',freq);

receiver = phased.ReceiverPreamp('Gain',Rx_Gain,'NoiseFigure',Noise_Figure,'LossFactor',Rx_Loss, 'ReferenceTemperature',290,'SampleRate',FS, ...
        'EnableInputPort',true,'SeedSource','Property','Seed',1e3);

channel = phased.FreeSpace('PropagationSpeed',physconst('LightSpeed'), 'OperatingFrequency',freq,'TwoWayPropagation',false, 'SampleRate',FS);

%% Steering
T = 1/PRF;
steer_Az = 0;
steer_El = 0;

steering2;

%% Simulation
%sum_rxsig = zeros(numsamples,numpulses);
%delta_rxsig = zeros(numsamples,numpulses);
%csig = zeros(numsamples,numpulses);
rxsig = zeros(size(sig));
numpulses = 100;                               % Number of Pulses

% Generate the pulse
for n = 1:numpulses
    % Update the Antenna position
    [txpos,txvel] = antennaplatform(T);
    % Update the target position
    [tgtpos,tgtvel] = targetplatform(T);
    % Get the range and angle to the target
    sig1 = zeros(size(sig,1),Cols/2);
    %size(sig1)
    for i = 1:Cols/2
        % Transmit the pulse. Output transmitter status
        [sig1(:,i),txstatus] = transmitter(sig);
    end
    
    %sig1 = sig1 .* w_all';
    % Radiate the pulse toward the target
    sig2 = radiator(sig1,[0;0]);
    clear sig1;
    % Propagate the pulse to the target in free space
    sig3 = channel(sig2,txpos,tgtpos,txvel,tgtvel);
    clear sig2;
    % Reflect the pulse off the target
    sig4 = target(sig3);
    clear sig3;
    % Propagate the echo to the antenna in free space
    sig5 = channel(sig4,tgtpos,txpos,tgtvel,txvel);
    clear sig4;
    % Collect the echo from the incident angle at the antenna
    sig6 = collector(sig5,[0;0]);
    clear sig5;
    % Receive the echo at the antenna when not transmitting
    xs=receiver(sig6,~txstatus);
    clear sig6;
    % Summing of 16 signals from Antenna
    y=zeros(size(sig));
    for j=1:16 
        y=y+xs(:,j);
    end
    clear xs;
    % Down-Conversion to 380MHz
    rxsig(:,n) = y;
end

%%
numsamples = size(sig,1);
del_t = T/numsamples;

t_axis = 0 : del_t : T-del_t;

down_freq = 9.985e9;
fs = 33.18e9;

w_freq = 2*pi*down_freq*t_axis;

xExp = exp(-1i*w_freq).';

xDwn = xExp .* rxsig;

yDwn2 = zeros(size(xDwn,1)/28,numpulses);

for i = 1:numpulses
    yDwn2(:,i) = decimate(xDwn(:,i), 28);
end
%% Convolution
x  = (fft(Baseband));
y1 = fft(yDwn2);
z  = x .* y1;
Z  = ifft(z);

%% Doppler Calculation

d = fftshift(fft(Z,numpulses,2),2);

f_axis = (-numpulses/2:numpulses/2-1)*PRF/(numpulses);

v_axis = f_axis*lambda/2;

R_axis = c*t_axis/2;

plot(v_axis,abs(d))
```

Some changes have been made. The peak at zero has moved but the velocity answer is at half. For example, when I enter 75 m/s it shows the peak at 150 m/s

[image: Velocity peak at -150 m/s when velocity entered is 75 m/s]

Comment: I think we’d require some more information on the data. You provide code only for the analysis, which is just a Fourier Transform of some data that is assumed to be correct. Well, the FFT seems to be done correctly, but I am not sure how this could be of help to you (but on the other hand, apart from generating axis values this is all you show here). I believe you should provide some more information on what exactly is that you are doing and possibly how as well as what the data are.

Comment: Yah, more information is definitely needed. Is your radar stationary? If so, it's very possible that it's clutter. But, more information is definitely needed to figure out why each of the peaks are where they are.

Comment: I am taking FFT of the data in slow time. These are the number of pulses. N = numpulses. I am taking its FFT. and then shifting it. Radar is stationery. Target is moving at speed of 50m/s

Comment: Please update to show the actual type of radar and how the signal is received / captured prior to sampling.

Comment: I have added the code for modeeling of the radar

Comment: @Waseem We still need more information. We can't be sure that you're simulating this correctly without knowing the relative positions of the radar (specifically the antenna) and the target. Even if you have a non-zero absolute target velocity, if it's moving perpendicular to the antenna face, you will get zero Doppler.

Comment: Antenna_Position=[0;0;4];              % Antenna Position [x y z]
Antenna_Velocity=[0;0;0];                       % Antenna Velocity [x y z]

Target_Velocity = [-50;0;0];                    % Target Velocity [x y z]
%Ts = 805;                                      % System Temperature

th_az = 0;
x_c = cosd(th_az);
y_c = sind(th_az);

R = 1200;

Target_Position = [ R*x_c; R*y_c; 4];                    % Target Position [x y z]f

Comment: antenna normal is towards x-axis.. radial velocity is 50m/s

Comment: @Waseem You really need to post your entire code that can be run to reproduce your results. Please update your post otherwise I don't think we can get to the bottom of your issue.

Comment: @Waseem Why is the 'TwoWayPropagation' property set to false? If you're transmitting and receiving, then you need two-way propagation. Still looking for other potential errors.

Comment: I am using the channel two-times. one for radiating and other for receiving.

Comment: @Waseem I don't have the Phased Array toolbox so I can't run this directly. One thing also to look at is your call to the collector inside the loop, it has an incoming angle of [0; 0] but that is not where your target is coming from based on the position. Also, mentioned anyone in comments with the "@" like I did here so we get notified of any responses.

Answer (score 1):

So this has been resolved. The issue was arising due to up-conversion and down-conversion. MATLAB Phased Array Toolbox is doing this conversion on its own. When I remove it, the signal showed peak at the required velocity and at zero m/s which was due to wrong summation of the received signal. Now, the results are correct. Contact me for more answers.